# Cannot install cordova camera plugin using Ionic 2 framework

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, plugins

I am trying to install cordova plugin for camera to use in Ionic 2 application, but I am keep getting error:

> Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-camera': CordovaError: Version of
>   installed plugin: "cordova-plugin-compat@1.0.0" does not satisfy
>   dependency plugin requirement "cordova-plugin-compat@^1.1.0". Try
>   --force to use installed plugin as dependency.

I tried removing cordova plugin compat and reinstalling it since I found many answers about this error on stackoverflow, but none of them worked for me. I also tried it with `--force` flag, but no success.

Also I tried: `cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-compat --force`
But I get an error:

> Error: Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin "cordova-plugin-camera". Please try adding it again.

I really hope anyone can help me since I am stuck here...
Thank you in beforehand.

Comment: http://blog.ionic.io/10-minutes-with-ionic-2-using-the-camera-with-ionic-native/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This might help you:

```
cordova plugin remove --force cordova-plugin-compat  
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-compat  
cordova platform remove android  
cordova platform add android  
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
```

Comment: I didn't need to uninstall the android platform, so only executed <br>
cordova plugin remove --force cordova-plugin-compat <br> 
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-compat<br>  
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera<br><br>

and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Work fine for me with:

1. ionic plugin rm --force cordova-plugin-compat
2. ionic plugin add --force cordova-plugin-compat
3. ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-camera

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks . This helped me

Answer (score 0):

I had to followed some steps:

1)Edit the file package-lock.json and delete the block from cordova-plugin-camera.
2)Enter in directory myproject/node_modules I delete the file cordova-plugin-camera
3)cordova plugin rm --force cordova-plugin-compat
4)cordova plugin add --force cordova-plugin-compat
5)cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera

and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

For me works this:

1. cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-compat --force
2. rm -rf ./plugins/cordova-plugin-compat/
3. cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-compat

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the `cordova-plugin-camera` comes with a version of `cordova-plugin-compat` which has been causing a version confusion. So I did this:

`ionic cordova plugin remove --force cordova-plugin-compat`
`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera`

No need to reinstall the `cordova-plugin-compat` after a successful install.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the above, and I was finally able to install the plugin by:

- removing the platform android
- removing compat
- installing new version of compat (1.1.0)
- installing camera plugin

All the above were successfull. But I am not able anymore to properly add the platform android and run it on my device.

I've created a thread for this : [Ionic 3 : Android add platform fails after installing cordova-plugin-camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46090844/ionic-3-android-add-platform-fails-after-installing-cordova-plugin-camera)

Answer (score 0):

Hi If you want to add cordova plugin into ionic v1 projecct you can do this steps

1. Remove android
   cordova platform remove android
2. Add Android
   cordova platform add android@5.0.0
3. Remove Cordova Compat plugin
   cordova plugin remove --force cordova-plugin-compat
4. Add Cordova compat plugin
   cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-compat
5. Add Cordova camera plugin
   cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
   or
   cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera.git

I succesfully install camera plugin in ionic v1 project.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing helped me - 
I did this

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera.git
```

as described here
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera

Comment: Mysteriously, this worked for me as well under different circumstances. Not sure why it is any different than 'cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera'